# Lagrange multipliers don't seem to work

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider the following constrained optimization problem:

$$
\min x^3+y^3
\\
\text{s.t.} x^2+y^2\leq 1
$$

From plotting this, the minima seems to be at $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$. Now, the KKT conditions become:

Lagrangian: $L = x^3+y^3+\lambda (-x^2-y^2+1)$ and
$\nabla L = 0$

$$=>3x^2-2\lambda x=0$$
$$3y^2-2\lambda y=0$$

Along with $\lambda \geq 0$

When we have $(-1,0)$ the first equation becomes:

$$\lambda = -\frac{3}{2}$$

Since this is contradiction with $\lambda \geq 0$, it seems the KKT conditions are not satisfied here. Isn't that problematic since this does appear to be the minima.

Comment: Why do you say $\lambda \geq 0$?  If you want that, then perhaps you can write $L=x^3+y^3+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$.

Comment: Isn't $\lambda \geq 0$ a part of the KKT conditions when we have an inequality constraint? This is of course when the problem is expressed in the standard form where all constraints are $\geq$, hence the need to multiply by -1.

Comment: You need to write the $L$ in the proper form in that case.

Comment: @michael what do you mean my "proper form"?

Comment: You have accidentally flipped the sign of the constraint function.  You want $x^2+y^2-1$ to be small, so you include it as $\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$, not $\lambda(1-x^2-y^2)$.

Comment: I think we need to flip it since in the standard form, all inequality constraints need to be $\geq$. Here, the constraint was $x^2+y^2\leq 1$. To convert it to a $ geq $ constraint, we need to multiply by $-1$. And only then can we apply the standard KKT conditions. Am I missing something?

Comment: See equations 12.30 on pg 328 here: http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf

Comment: You likely are applying some formula incorrectly, or you have typos in your formulas.  Don't loose the intuition:  You want both $x^3+y^3$ to be small, and $x^2+y^2-1$ to be small, so the idea is to minimize the weighted sum $x^3+y^3 + \lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$ for some $\lambda\geq 0$.

Comment: If I do that, the exact same dilemma will be transferred to the point $(1,0)$ which should be the maxima.

Comment: No, in fact if you do that then you can get $(x,y)=(0,-1)$ and $\lambda = 3/2$ is a solution to the stated minimization problem, as is $(x,y)=(-1,0)$ and $\lambda = 3/2$.

Comment: What if I were looking for the maxima instead?

Comment: If you want to maximize the objective function, while keeping the same constraint, you note that you want both $-x^3 -y^3$ and $x^2+y^2-1$ to be small, so you use $L=-x^3 -y^3 + \lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$ (with $\lambda \geq 0$).

Comment: Hmm, sure. But this still doesn't seem to agree with eq 12.30 in the book I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general framework is this: Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, g_i:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$. The optimization problem is: 
\begin{align}
\mbox{Minimize:} \quad & f(x) \\
\mbox{Subject to:} \quad & g_i(x) \leq 0 \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., k\}\\
& x \in \mathcal{X}
\end{align}
Now you want to "simultaneously" make $f(x), g_1(x), ..., g_k(x)$ small, so to do that you minimize a weighted sum
$$ L(x;\lambda)= f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i g_i(x)$$
for some multipliers $\lambda_i\geq 0$.  It turns out that minimizing $L$ over all $x \in X$ is useful for general (possibly non-differentiable) problems, as is finding stationary points of $L$ for differentiable problems.

Comment: Some books/notes/wikipedia articles try to tell you to do separate things when you are maximizing versus minimizing...I think this ends up being confusing (you end up trying to memorize formulas versus trying to keep the intuition).  It is easy enough to convert any optimization problem you want into the above form. Now if you want equality constraints $h_j(x)=0$  you can also use the above form with $h_j(x)\leq 0$ and $-h_j(x)\leq 0$, or you can simply allow yourself to use multipliers $\mu_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the answer and your patience. One thing I still can't fathom. Your inequality constraints are in direct contradiction with equation 12.1 of Nocedal and Wright where they express them as $\geq$. Further, they also reach the same conclusion ($\lambda_i \geq 0$) for inequalities in equation 12.30. Both these formulations can't be simultaneously correct and this is what I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Well, here is a wikipedia article that is consistent with my above framework (ignore the "for maximizing" there, just look at "for minimizing"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions The wikipedia is still too prescriptive for my taste as it tries to differentiate $L$ for you, and set the result to zero, so you have to reverse-engineer that to see what $L$ is being used. But the "for minimizing" case is consistent with the $L$ that I use.

Comment: @RohitPandey Do Nocedal and Wright have a minus sign instead of a plus sign in the Lagrangian?

Comment: Yes, they do. Thanks!